# Can Matlab check the spelling error of certain article/paragraph?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Can Matlab check the spelling error of certain article/paragraph? or do Matlab have any vocabulary to check the error of the content?

There is no spelling error in example, while there is 4 spelling error in example 2 (usuali, o, sistem, nombor)

example1
**no spelling error:**
Traditionally in English, an article is usually considered to be a type of adjective. In some languages, articles are a special part of speech, which cannot easily be combined with other parts of speech. It is also possible for articles to be part of another part of speech category such as a determiner, an English part of speech category that combines articles and demonstratives (such as 'this' and 'that')

Then the output will return 1 if got spelling error, else -1

example2
**got spelling error:**
Articles are usuali characterized as either definite o indefinite.[2] A few languages with well-developed sistem of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article, according to grammatical attributes such as gender, nombor, or case, or according to adjacent sounds.

```
Output:
example1: -1
example2: 1
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91885

Comment: I get an error:

"??? Input argument "word" is undefined.

Error in ==> word at 10 correct = h.CheckSpelling(word);"

I have installed ActiveX, but not sure how to use and run with the code, can somebody help?